# Paginated JSON Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, pagination

I'm trying to figure out to create a collection of image urls pulling from a third party api that  currently renders their JSON as paginated with only 5 images per page. I'm not sure how to structure my parse method so that I can collect twenty urls at the outset.

I'm confused about what to call my url so that it I can just follow the 'next page' link. One approach that I was thinking of was to create two collections- a base collection that instantiates another collection with different endings for the 'url' until the desired amount of urls is achieved.

My JSON looks like:

```
{ data: [url1, url2, url3, url4, url5],
  pagination: {current_page: 2, next_page: "link1", previous_page: "link3", per_page: 5}  
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the API limits you to the 5 images per page? I would suspect that 5 is a default, and that you will find the possibility of increasing that in the API with a different setting somewhere.

Comment: thanks- I just added a query string and now it works- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given your scenario, where one fetch was dependent on the last fetch (For the next_link), I thought a little recursion may be helpful. You could do successive fetches that fire upon a server response. I would create the following function in my view:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.numOfFetches = 5 // Depends on how many urls you want to end up with

    // Start the recursion
    this.fetchUrls(this); // Pass int the context so it'll be available throughout
                          // the recursion
  }

  fetchUrls: function (context) {
    this.collection.fetch({remove: false})
    // Backbone.sync returns jQuery Promises
    // so we can take advantage of the Promise methods
    .done(function(response) {
      if (--context.numOfFetches > 0) {
        // Set up the url for the next fetch
        context.collection.url = response.pagination.next_page
        // Iterate the recursion
        context.fetchUrls(context); 
      }
    })
    // Do something different if the call fails
    .fail(function() {
      // If you want to fetch the next page even on fail
      // you can use the .always() Promise method instead of
      // .done() and remove this .fail() method
    })
  }
});
```

A couple of points. First, notice how we pass the `{ remove: false }` option to `collection.fetch`. This is crucial. It tells `collection.set` to add (or merge existing) models as the data returns from the server. Without it, it would remove all models that do not match the last response. Second, I attached a `numOfFetches` property to your view (in `intialize` for convenience), because the recursion would need a variable in a parent scope that would not be re-initialized with every recursion.

Third, given the object you're going receive to receive from the API, you'd likely would want to do some parsing on the response. Let me know if you need some pointers on how to efficiently manage the models for this collection.